# Why has networking for my 12.04 setup stopped working?

Tags: networking, 12.04, intel, iwlwifi

I have a Thinkpad X201 with an Intel-based network card with an N-6200 WiFi. All of a sudden neither ethernet nor Wifi works. I get a DHCP address, and can connect to local LAN resources (via HTTP or other protocols), but can't get beyond the router. This is not specific to a network, as I have had this issue at home, but also on the road.

I have an XP Virtual box machine that I'm running as a guest. If I change the network config in Virtual Box to "bridged" and give myself a static IP address in the Windows guest session with an external DNS entry (e.g. 8.8.8.8) I can get get Internet access.

Also if I boot to a Live USB on the same hardware, same network, no issues.

I have already disabled N networking on the WLAN interface, but that doesn't fix it, but of course has no effect on ethernet.

Help!!!!

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 5c:ff:35:04:ab:de  
          inet addr:192.168.1.29  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::5eff:35ff:fe04:abde/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:21563 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:17982 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:18938624 (18.9 MB)  TX bytes:1921823 (1.9 MB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:f2500000-f2520000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:1693 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1693 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:606855 (606.8 KB)  TX bytes:606855 (606.8 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:23:14:7a:bf:78  
          inet addr:192.168.1.28  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::223:14ff:fe7a:bf78/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2528 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:610 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:427700 (427.7 KB)  TX bytes:100284 (100.2 KB)

$ iwconfig

lo        no wireless extensions.

vboxnet0  no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:"MANUKAI_1"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: 4C:60:DE:2E:CC:C4   
          Bit Rate=1 Mb/s   Tx-Power=15 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-7 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:61   Missed beacon:0

eth0      no wireless extensions.

$ lspci

00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 02) 
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02) 
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset HECI Controller (rev 06) 
00:16.3 Serial controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset KT Controller (rev 06)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82577LM Gigabit Network Connection (rev 06) 
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio (rev 06) 
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 06) 
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev 06) 
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev 06) 
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 06) 
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev a6) 
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 5 Series Chipset LPC Interface Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 6 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 06) 
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset SMBus Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset Thermal Subsystem (rev 06) 
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6200 (rev 35) 
ff:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-core Registers (rev 02) 
ff:00.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture System Address Decoder (rev 02) 
ff:02.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Link 0 (rev 02) 
ff:02.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Physical 0 (rev 02) 
ff:02.2 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Reserved (rev 02) 
ff:02.3 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Reserved (rev 02)
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, I appear to have solved this... it appears tat something at some point overwrote my /etc/resolv.conf with the address of my home router (192.168.0.1). I changed this to include Google's public DNS (8.8.8.8) and sure enough it now works... Not sure what would overwrite this.

Comment: If something is overwriting /etc/resolv.conf to contain "nameserver 192.168.0.1" then probably your router's DHCP server is giving out this address as the address of the nameserver to use. If that isn't right then the DHCP server needs to be reconfigured to vie out another address such as 8.8.8.8 instead. What did the overwriting --- resolvconf or something else?